# What is better, generating a CSRF Token per form request or having a Session Key that is stored in the DB?

Tags: php

The title basically explains itself, would it be a good idea if I made a Session token upon login that has its own Session token generated with BCRYPT and verified that way?

Answer (score 2):

They serve completely different purposes. Even if you created your own session token you'll need some way for the client to send you that token to retrieve their session. CSRF tokens invalidate people from making forms off site that post by hijacking peoples sessions.

Personally, I don't think it's worth changing the default way sessions are managed in PHP apart from [forcing secure cookies for session IDs](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-secure).

Completely different. Please let me know if you want me to elaborate a little more.

Comment: The session token would consist of user data (maybe User ID, Email, Pass, IP, just random variables that are in it) that are hashed with some type of encryption... And then that's in the database, and then when you log in it will verify the session token and etc.

Comment: So the session token would be used on every form as the CSRF token? Are you asking whether it's worth generating a token for each individual form request or just for all from request over one session? In either case the database and user data should not be involved...

Comment: I made a CSRF Class, but I have no idea if it's good enough for what I need it to do. So I'm asking if there's certain ways I should do it. I can show you what I have. And if my CSRF path is good or not.

Comment: The most important thing is that you have a CSRF token attached to _every_ form. The CSRF token can be generated on login, but it should just be a random string - 32 bytes should do. Save that in the session. Now for every form you need to validate that the form sends the same token you have in session. This means I can't write a form that posts to your site (on my site), and get someone who is logged into your site to use my form (I can't know the CSRF token).

Comment: But should I make the token re-generate itself every form submission?

Comment: It does provide extra security. Someone could technically scour a form  (especially if you're not using https) for your CSRF token, then quickly edit their form, but's a pretty directed attack. Once per login is good enough.